# Increment int variable every 5 iterations of loop (JAVA)

Tags: java, loops, iteration, increment

i want to Increment int variable every 5 iterations of loop. so the current int is 009. I want to change it to an infinite loop wherein the value add + 1 every 5 loops. so after that the value of 009 will change to 010, then after 5 loops. again it will change into 011.

```
 String itemID = "2014-009";
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        String sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(new java.util.Date());
        String[] parts = itemID.split("-");
        String part2 = parts[1];
        int result = Integer.parseInt(part2);
        String second = sdf + "-" + String.format("%03d", result + 1);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, second);
        System.out.println(second);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
int value = 0;
for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
    if (i%5 == 0) {
        value++;
    }
}
```

Explanation:

- The loop has no end, because it doesn't have a condition
- The `value` variable is incremented only every 5 iterations
- We enforce that restriction by asking whether `i` is exactly divided by `5`

Be aware that I'm not taking into account the fact that `int`s are *finite* and at some point they will overflow. For truly "infinite" values (limited only by the memory available in your machine), we would have to use arbitrary precision values, `BigInteger` will come in handy for that.

Comment: I've tried this but it just count from 1 to infinity. :(

Comment: @user3416315 you can't count "to infinity", memory and data types have limits. And I don't know what you "have tried", but the above code will increment the `value` variable only when the `i` variable has been incremented five times.

Comment: I have a follow up question sir. how about when I set the value of variable int i 16. i want to count 16 as another 5 how about that? 

so the output of value will be 1 2 3 4  instead of just 1 2 3

Comment: @user3416315 the question is not clear. Maybe add another `if` in the loop, to test whether `i == 16`? if that doesn't work, please reformulate the followup as a new question and post it

Comment: Sorry for that. Here, I'll rephrase it. What if i set the termination of the loop to 16 (for (int i=0;i<16,i++)). I want to count the 16 as another 5 so it will go into another loop and it also increases the int value.

Comment: Increment the `value` outside the loop, after it exits. Or set the condition as `i < 16+5`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should initialize result outside the loop.
Then you can do an infinite loop with a counter that checks if the iteration is divisable by 5 :

```
....
int result = Integer.parseInt(part2);
int i = 0;

while (true) {
    i++;
    if (i%5 == 0)
        result++;
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(float i=0; i<10; i=i+0.2f){
     System.out.println((int) i);
}
```

You can adapt the rest

Answer (score 0):

In my case all above works on first iteration because 0%5 == 0 in my case is true and I suggest to write code like this:

```
if(i%5 == 0 && i != 0) {//6 threads per one operation
   lq1.join();
   lq2.join();
}
```